# issue with reading data from csv file to a dataset

Tags: csv, datastage

I need your help
I have an easy datastage job.
the source is a  csv file and the target is a dataset.
im using a transformer between to do some transformations.
the first column in my csv contains numbers defined as string.
I have for exemple 3 records,
0234,xxxx,date1

0121,yyyy,date2

0898,zzzz,date3

I use a right function to extract the first column and load it to my dataset on string column (the target field is a string(4))
so I use this function on my transformer :
right(namecolumn1,4)
and i get this on my dataset :
234
121
898
instead of this
0234
0121
0898

can anyone help me plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the target column is Char or VarChar, not Integer.  DataStage will remove leading zeroes from integers, but not from string data types.

Comment: hello, the target is varchar 4